# How To Convert Time Into This Format

Tags: mysql

I was very frustated to change this. i have this data in mysql :

```
    |  waktudw     |
    |--------------|
    |    00:10:00  |
    |    01:50:00  |
```

i want to the result like this

```
    |  waktudw     |
    |--------------|
    |    10 Menit  |
    |1 Jam 50 Menit|
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use MINUTE() and HOUR() but in any date format. If the value is string you need to convert to date.

Below is example sql and i use NOW() as date value :

```
select concat(MINUTE(now()), ' Menit')  ;
select concat(HOUR(now()), ' Jam')  ;
select concat(HOUR(now()), ' Jam ',MINUTE(now()), ' Menit')  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DATE_FORMAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) or [`TIME_FORMAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format) to convert the TIME value to a specific string format.

```
MariaDB [test]> SELECT NOW(), TIME(NOW()), DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%k Jam %i Menit');
+---------------------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| NOW()               | TIME(NOW()) | DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%k Jam %i Menit') |
+---------------------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 2017-10-23 09:42:30 | 09:42:30    | 9 Jam 42 Menit                        |
+---------------------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
```